# How to include everything on the final app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a project that is using 2 static libraries I have created, lets call them libraryA and libraryB and a Bundle.

The main project uses libraryA, libraryB and the bundle and libraryA also have calls to libraryB and the bundle.

Every static library, the bundle and the main project were created by initiating a new project in Xcode. The last project to be created was MyProject.xcodeproj. After creating that project I dragged libraryA.xcodeproj, libraryB.xcodeproj and myBundle.xcodeproj to it and ended with something like this:

[image]

Everything is compiling and running beautifully but inspecting inside MyProject.app, I see it did not contain the resource files that are inside myBundle. Yes, myBundle.bundle is on "copy bundle resources" phase of MyProject and also on the target dependencies.

BTW, please explain me how should I set the "target dependencies", "link binary with libraries" and "copy bundle resources" sections of build phases for all parts of this project, so the final app will include everything.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target Dependencies just means which other targets will be executed first before your current target builds. If you want to pick up changes to library's and bundles before compiling the main project, then make sure each of those targets are included. The project will still build fine if you remove them from dependencies, you just will have to manually build the libraries' projects when you want to add changes.

Link with binary libraries should show both libraryA and B. It will reference the latest built version of that library, so combined with the target dependencies, your MyProject app will have all of the latest changes to your libraries.

If your MyProject app is running fine, chances are you did everything correctly. If you can reference classes in the static libraries without getting linker errors, then those are being linked correctly. If the resources from myBundle are showing up in the app's UI, then that is being copied over properly as well.

If you're missing files from the bundle, look in your MyBundle project and make sure that its Copy Bundle Resources section shows the files you want included.

Comment: MyBundle.bundle contains all resources but MyProject.app that is the final application similar to the one that will be submitted to apple does not. At least I am not seeing any of the bundle images inside that.

Comment: after deleting the dependencies/copy resources and adding them again, they are now included on the app. Thanks.